# MongoDB Compass Error in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-20.04, mongodb-compass

Running compass stop and now it's giving below error on Ubuntu 20.04

`mongodb-compass: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I uninstall and then install the error is still the same. even I tried the old version too. I searched and found this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089381/cannot-open-mongodb-compass-in-ubuntu-18-10) but it does not work for me.

[SS of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vW9B.jpg)